# Symmetric matrix congruent with diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, congruences, diagonalization

I want to find a matrix $M$ satisfying
$$M^TPM=D$$
where

1. $P$ is a known symmetric square matrix.
2. $D$ is a unknown diagonal matrix.

This problem is a matrix congruence problem. We can think of this problem as an eigenvalue problem, but in order to do so, we must additionally consider the assumption that $M$ is orthonormal.
However, such assumptions can not be used in this problem.

This is a congruence problem of symmetric matrix and I hope someone can help me.

Comment: There is some information missing, e.g. $M=0$ always solves this (and I assume you wouldn't want something like that)

Comment: If you are working with real-valued matrices it _follows_ from the fact that $P$ is symmetric that you can choose $M$ to be orthogonal - it is not an _assumption_.

Comment: Also, two elements $a,b$ of a let's say group are called congruent if there is an element $c$, such that  $c^{-1}ac = b$, so this is not really a congruence problem unless you require $M^{-1} = M^T$.

Comment: @Andrew In my knowledge, $M^-1PM=D$ relation is defined as similarity not congruence.

Comment: I'm with @MårtenW. Unless you're working over other fields.

Comment: @MårtenW Could you explain in more detail theoretical basis of the answer?

Comment: @Mathematician42 Could you explain why you agree with MartenW?

Comment: @J.Kim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization You will find your answer (why Marten is right) in this paragraph.

Comment: Any real symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable, this is the so called spectral theorem (which holds in a much more general setting as well).